# How to add Block into another one - Magento 2

Tags: magento, frontend, block, magento2

what's up!

I need a little help.
I am trying to create some blocks usign the code below:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Gysa\Quotes\Block\Adminhtml\Quotes\Edit" name="quotes_quotes_edit" template="Gysa_Quotes::quote/create/form.phtml">
        <block class="Gysa\Quotes\Block\Adminhtml\Quotes\Edit\Products" template="Gysa_Quotes::quote/create/products.phtml" name="quotes_quotes_edit_products" />
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

But the block "quotes_quotes_edit_products" doens't showing up.  I have looked some examples on "Magento Sales" and there I can see that is possible. So What Am I doing wrong.

Anyone Can help please.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you called getChildHtml in your wrapping template?

Answer (score 0):

It might sound silly but have you cleared cache?
Also it would help to see if the block is loaded if you enable the template hints

Comment: I have. thanks
That's no silly. Magento Cache has droven me crazy quite often. 

I have done about that but I am stil on with doubt.
I used the alias to sort it but I pretty sure that is possible to solve in a better way.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Just Change It :-**

```
  <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Gysa\Quotes\Block\Adminhtml\Quotes\Edit" name="quotes_quotes_edit" template="Gysa_Quotes::quote/create/form.phtml">
    name="quotes_quotes_edit_products" />
    </block>
<refernceBlock name="quotes_quotes_edit">
    <block class="Gysa\Quotes\Block\Adminhtml\Quotes\Edit\Products" template="Gysa_Quotes::quote/create/products.phtml" 
</refernceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak.

I wil try it